# strange behaviour of setText on String

Tags: java, android

Why this code works well only because I add `SS+""` instead of `SS`, in the `setText`
the Textview don't display the value but W- or W instead of the value

```
    binding.slider.addOnChangeListener(new Slider.OnChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(Slider slider, float value, boolean fromUser) {
      float Wmref = (int)value;
      Locale decimalPointLocale = Locale.US;
      String SS = String.format(decimalPointLocale, "W%5.0f", Wmref);
      binding.Wmref.setText(SS+"");
      Log.d(TAG, "Wmref="+SS);
      myWebSocketClient.sendMessage(SS);
    }
  });
```

Comment: By the way, var names start with lowercase letter in Java conventions.

Comment: `float Wmref = (int)value;` **danger** Will Robinson.

Comment: @Will: Why? I want to get the integer part of my float value 123.0 not 123.5

Comment: @Lotfi Whoops. Deleting my comment

Comment: and now even with SS+"" it doesn't display well, it shows W or W -  (for negative value, and no numbers, strange

Comment: Do you want 123.0 or do you want 123? `String SS = String.format("W%5s", (int) 123.5);`

Comment: sorry I want 123 of course